# Is it possible to animate a view form one ViewController into the next?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uipageviewcontroller, translate-animation

So I am trying to set up a `UIPageViewController`, and I have several `UIViewControllers`, but I want to set it up so I can animate(translate) a subview of my first view controller into the second view controller as it is transitioning. I have the `UIPageViewController` transition set to scroll. So that is what makes me believe this should be possible correct me if I am wrong. My google searches came up empty, but perhaps I am searching for the wrong thing.

Please point me in the right direction here in the form of a tut or how to conceptually think about this. My current thought is that I could have two identical views in different controllers, and as the user swipes the first view travels from left to right and then when I know it is at the edge I could have the other view take over perhaps using the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for custom transitions. So the keywords to search for are "uiviewcontroller custom transition". That will give you this tutorial for instance: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions or this one: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/ or this description from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html Hope that was what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Hero library (https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) for custom animations between UIViewControllers. 
Since a PageViewController doesn't really allow custom animation have a look at the AppleHomePageExample to see a example.

Comment: is it possible to change the speed of the transition in hero ?